# Adding padding: 0 20px; doesn’t work with added borders

Tags: css, youtube, padding

How would I get it to work with added borders?

Left side is 21px right side is 14px.

What would I need to adjust in the code?

```
.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Code
https://jsfiddle.net/udsav90r/2/

[image]

Full Code:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.video-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 789px;
  margin: auto;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Comment: One thing was missing: `border-collapse: collapse;`
You need to add this to the `tcell` class

Comment: or , might be about box-sizing : `* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box
}` , a short and usefull reset ...  https://jsfiddle.net/scwnq7yh/